# http Dart package examples are outdated, how to use client.get()

Tags: flutter, http, dart, flutter-http

Here's the second example given by the http package: https://pub.dev/packages/http

```
var client = http.Client();
try {
  var uriResponse = await client.post('https://example.com/whatsit/create',
      body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
  print(await client.get(uriResponse.bodyFields['uri']));
} finally {
  client.close();
}
```

I get error: `uriResponse.bodyFields['uri'] no such method.`

I can see that there's no property named bodyFields in the class Response: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response-class.html

So how should I use the `client.get()`?

I checked the docs for the function https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/get.html and I wrote this:

```
print(await client.get(uriResponse.request.url, {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
}));
```

But this also fails with error:

```
Class 'IOClient' has no instance method 'get' with matching arguments.
E/flutter (19613): Receiver: Instance of 'IOClient'
E/flutter (19613): Tried calling: get(Instance of '_SimpleUri', Instance of '_CompactLinkedHashSet<Map<String, String>>')
E/flutter (19613): Found: get(dynamic, {Map<String, String> headers}) => Future<Response>
```

Comment: Your `client.get` attempt needs to use `client.get(..., headers: { ... })` because the `headers` parameter is *named*.  The issue about the incorrect example is https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/173.

Comment: It fixes the errors thanks, but according to the docs, client.get() should return a instance of the Response class but when I check, it's always empty. Have checked multiple websites including example.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your `post` as below and print the response  separate.

```
final response = await client.post(
    '*endPoint url*',
    headers: *headers if you have any*,
    body: jsonEncode({'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'}
    ));

print(json.decode((response.body)));
```

and follow the same structure for the `get` method as well.

Comment: Same structure for GET, causes error: `Exception has occurred.
ClientException (Content size below specified contentLength.  0 bytes written but expected 793.)`

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "url";
Response response = await client.get(url);
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${json.decode((response.body))}');
```

Comment: please comment your code and explain your answer to make it more usefull